# Flutter Error: Because mi_card depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have the following `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

When I run the update command to change the dependencies, I get the following error:

> The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.
>
> Because mi_card depends on cupertino_icons >=0.1.1 <1.0.1 which
> doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.
>
> The lower bound of "sdk: '<2.0.0 or >=2.0.0-dev.28.0 <3.0.0'" must be
> 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety. For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety
>
> You can try the following suggestion to make the pubspec resolve:
>
> - Try upgrading your constraint on cupertino_icons: flutter pub add cupertino_icons:^1.0.6

I was expecting to update the dependencies, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Bheem!

It seems that you are using an old version of the `cupertino_icons` package which does **not** support null safety.

### One step upgrade

The easiest way to solve this issue is to upgrade your package dependencies to the latest version.

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Or

```
flutter pub add cupertino_icons:^1.0.6
```

> Note: If you do not know the available version, ask for version suggestion for a single package with the `flutter pub upgrade cupertino_icons` command. It will recommend you to another upgrade command with version specification.

### Two step upgrade

Alternatively, you can upgrade one package by removing the package and then adding it back. Execute the following commands in your terminal.

```
flutter pub remove cupertino_icons
```

It will remove the `cupertino_icons` package. Look at the `pubspec.yaml` file, and you will see no Cupertino package. To add back the package, run this command:

```
flutter pub add cupertino_icons
```

Make sure that the Cupertino package is added to the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: oh! i got it, thank you!
sorry for informing late, i was in a remote location.

Comment: @Bheem You're welcome. In this case, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was manually editing the cupertino_icons field to ^1.0.6 in my pubspec.yaml file, and then running “Get Dependencies” in my main.dart file.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run flutter pub upgrade --major-versions cmd in your android studio terminal then change cupertino_icons version.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

1. First Click 'Get Dependencies'.
2. Still error not resolved then run code in terminal `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` before that change `sdk: ">3.0.0"` in yaml file